# unselect other item when click a item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i use this code to show 3 message "backs" "back" "backx"
When I click on one item, the class (background, color) will be changed for that and also will show a popup. In addition, the item will be "selected".
Actually when I click on the second item, that will be "selected" form like the first item, it means we will have 2 items "selected" form, but I want, when I click on the second item it will be selected and the first item will be Unselected.

```
  <div id="toggler"><div id="sxx" ><span  id="pnotify-no-title">backx</span></div>      
          <div id="toggler"><div id="sxx1" ><span  id="pnotify-no-title">backs</span></div>
        <div id="toggler"><div id="sxx2" ><span  id="pnotify-no-title">back</span></div>


$(function(){
$('#sxx1').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('sxz')) {
        $(this).removeClass('sxz');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('sxz');
    }
    $('#sx1').toggle();
});

});//]]> 
$(function(){
$('#sxx').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('sxz')) {
        $(this).removeClass('sxz');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('sxz');
    }
    $('#sx').toggle();
});

});//]]> 
$(function(){
$('#sxx2').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('sxz')) {
        $(this).removeClass('sxz');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('sxz');
    }
    $('#sx2').toggle();
});

});//]]> 
 $('#pnotify-no-title').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    new PNotify({
        text: $this.hasClass('odd-click') ? 'two' : 'one',
        addclass: $this.hasClass('odd-click') ? 'bg-warning' : 'bg-primary'

    });

    $this.toggleClass('odd-click');
});
 $('#pnotify-no-title1').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    new PNotify({
        text: $this.hasClass('odd-click') ? 'two' : 'one',
        addclass: $this.hasClass('odd-click') ? 'bg-warning' : 'bg-primary'

    });

    $this.toggleClass('odd-click');
});
 $('#pnotify-no-title2').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    new PNotify({
        text: $this.hasClass('odd-click') ? 'two' : 'one',
        addclass: $this.hasClass('odd-click') ? 'bg-warning' : 'bg-primary'

    });

    $this.toggleClass('odd-click');
});
```

Comment: Just unselect the other items whenever an item is selected...

Comment: You're using `#sx1` when your ID is `sxx1`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sxx, #sxx1, #sxx2').click(function() {
    $('.sxz').removeClass('sxz');
    $(this).addClass('sxz');
}
```

only one element can be active - https://jsfiddle.net/4nddao1n/

Comment: hi i dont understand it,please help me

Comment: @Pasha instead of posting only code please also add an explanation what the code does